# Change single location based on server name in Nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a server entry on my configurations with like 50 location entry
i need to define another domain on my server with the same configuration except for one location

for example i have

```
server {

    # the port your site will be served on
    # the domain name it will serve for
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com sudomain.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/loc/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/loc/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    location /static/ {
        root /srv/sites/example;
    }
... # many more location defenition


}
```

i need to do something like

```
    location /robots.txt {
        if ($host ~ ^\w+\.\w+\.\w+$) { 
            # subdomains
            alias /srv/robots_disallow.txt;
        } else {
            alias /srv/robots.txt;
        }
    }
```

if it's possible i want to avoid extracting all the configuration into a snippet and then including it in 2 server entry one for main domain one for subdomain.

I know the code that i have copied doesn't work and i have read [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

which suggests something

```
    error_page 418 = @disallow_robots;
    location /robots.txt {
        alias /srv/robots.txt;

        if ($host ~ ^\w+\.\w+\.\w+$) { 
            # subdomains
            return 418;
        }
    }

    location @disallow_robots {
        alias /srv/robots_disallow.txt;
    }
```

But then i get `the "alias" directive cannot be used inside the named location`

Answer (score 1):

You will achieve a cleaner solution with a `map` and a `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
map $host $robots {
    ~^\w+\.\w+\.\w+$ /robots_disallow.txt;
    default          /robots.txt;
}

server {
    ...

    location = /robots.txt {
        root /srv;
        try_files $robots =404;
    }

    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.